# Unsplit tabs in iterm

Tags: iterm

I had attempted to `tear` a tab from `iterm` by dragging it out into its own window.  Somehow the result instead is that it were added as a second `panel` below the first one:

[image]

Now how can either of the following be done:

- tear either of the two `panes` out to their own window
- reset both split `panes` to instead be `tab`s again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press the little icon on the right hand edge of the dividing bar you can select `Move Session to Window`

[image]

Comment: wow man how do you find these things?  I should learn to just "click on every darn icon on the entire screen".  When they are not in any menu it sucks for keyboardists like me.